# C++ class unittests (Qt and not only)

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I am pretty new to `C++` `unit testing` and I am in the following situation:
I have a class which is (of course) has `public` and `private` members. I want to test a method from `private/protected` section. For tests I use `QtTest` package but it is not strict requirement. Which is the best way of test such method?

My suggestions are:

```
1. Subclass it with `Test class` (multiple inheritance)
2. Add friend class (not the best way in my opinion)
```

Comment: I use google test and typically will do the subclass method to access protected members and try to test without accessing the private parts directly. Seems like there ought to be unit test packages that could work around the private issue, but I haven't seen anything myself. Would be interested if there is something useful out there.

Comment: If the functionality can be separated out into a new class that gives you the best of both worlds -- no funny tricks are needed, and you end up with a leaner class that can be separately tested and documented.

Comment: Testing private member functions is unusual, and usually a sign that you either don't understand the value of unit testing, or think the value is higher than it actually is. Don't test private member functions. Also, this is really subjective.